# c++ Login System - How do I return the username?

Tags: c++, return-type, login-system

I am a beginner programmer, and have just started using classes and objects so please excuse the mess I have made.

The objective of this function is to check if a username file exists, if it exists return the username to the main.cpp, so that I can then store it in the main and use it to update that specific file if needed.

From my current research you can't return a string or character array, from similar cases they have suggested using vectors instead, would this be the right path for me to go down or is there another solution? I also know that I have used void and no return type as of this point (Was for testing purposes).
//Login class file

```
void Login::UserSelectLogin()
{
    Draw Gotoxy;
    Draw ObjectLogin;
    Draw ObjectBorder;

    string password;
    string userName;
    bool loginSucceed;

    do
    {
        system("CLS");
        ObjectBorder.Border();
        ObjectLogin.Login();

        //USER INPUTS
        Gotoxy.gotoxy(27, 6);
        cin >> userName;
        Gotoxy.gotoxy(27, 7);
        cin >> password;

        if (ifstream(userName))
            return userName;
        else
        {
            Gotoxy.gotoxy(30, 8);
            cout << "USER ALREADY EXISTS";
            loginSucceed = false;
            _getch();
        }
    } while (loginSucceed != true);

}
```

//Header File

```
#ifndef LOGIN_H
#define LOGIN_H
#include <string>

class Login
{
public:
    Login();
    string UserSelectLogin();
    void UserSelectNewUser();
};
#endif
```

//main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    SetWindow(80, 22);
    Draw ObjectBorder;
    Draw ObjectLoginOrNewUser;
    Draw ObjectLogin;
    Draw ObjectNewUser;
    Draw ObjectOptionsMenu;
    Draw ObjectMap;
    Draw ObjectBattleScreen;
    Draw ObjectGotoxy;

    Login LoginUser;
    Login CreateNewUser;

    string userName;

    char firstScreenChoice;

    bool gameQuit = false;
    do
    {
        ObjectBorder.Border();
        ObjectLoginOrNewUser.LoginOrNewUser();

        firstScreenChoice = _getch();
        switch (firstScreenChoice)
        {
        case '1':
            userName = LoginUser.UserSelectLogin();
            _getch();
            break;
        case '2':
            CreateNewUser.UserSelectNewUser();
            _getch();
            break;
        default:
            system("CLS");
            ObjectBorder.Border();
            cout << "INVALID INPUT";
            _getch();
        }
        system("CLS");
    } while (gameQuit != true);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, you can't return a string? `std::string Login::SelectUserLogin() { std::string str; ... return str; }`

Answer (score 2):

You can return a string by value. Just declare the function to return a `std::string` and use something like `return userName;` in the function.

Comment: C2039 'UserSelectLogin': is not a member of 'Login' Alpha 1.4 
Error C2039 'string': is not a member of 'std' Alpha 1.4 
Error C3646 'UserSelectLogin': unknown override specifier 8
Error C2059 syntax error: '(' Alpha 1.4 e:\game development\game dev\alpha 1.4\alpha 1.4\login.h 8
Error C2238 unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
Error C2039 'string': is not a member of 'std'
Error C3646 'UserSelectLogin': unknown override specifier
Error C2059 syntax error: '(' Alpha 1.4 e:\game 
Error C2238 unexpected token(s) preceding ';' Alpha 1.4 
Error C2039 'UserSelectLogin': is not a member of 'Login'

Comment: It just chucks those errors when I tried those changes, would it help if I posted the main.cpp code and function definitions as well?

Comment: It sounds like you need to `#include <string>` in your file here.

Comment: Additionally, you're being told that `Login::UserSelectLogin()` was not declared in the class definition, so make sure you put `void UserSelectLogin();` (or `std::string UserSelectLogin();`, if you're trying to implement that) in your `Login` class somewhere.

Comment: #ifndef LOGIN_H
#define LOGIN_H
#include <string>

class Login
{
public:
 Login();
 string UserSelectLogin();
 void UserSelectNewUser();
};
#endif

Comment: Im not sure how to format comments, but thats my Login.h file, it has the string userSelectLogin(); also my Login.cpp has the #include <string>

Comment: @MaxMcgregor Read each error carefully, think about it, punch it into your favorite search engine if necessary, and fix it. Go in order because earlier errors can make later error messages confusing.

Comment: and dont post code or errors as comments - they are impossible to read. Update the question. But only after trying to analyze whats going on

Answer (score 0):

> if a username file exists, if it exists return the username to the
>   main.cpp, so that I can then store it in the main and use it to update
>   that specific file if needed.

You might consider moving the string userName to be a formal parameter (pass by reference) ...

```
void Login::UserSelectLogin(std::string& userName)
{
   ...
```

No return of userName needed (which your code is missing the return type)

Caution: you probably should ensure that userName.size() will be 0 when login fails. (i.e. set it to null string)

```
userName = "";
```

---

update: usage note

with the declaration above, and an implementation like:

```
void Login::UserSelectLogin(std::string& userName){ /*..implementation..*/ };
```

Then, in main or from any function, you would invoke with:

```
 // assume
 Login  aLogin; // default ctor
 // ... 

 // ... time to fetch login name
 std::string aUserName;  // default ctor creates null string
 aLogin.UserSelectLogin(aUserName);  // formal parameter is local var
 // ... continue
```

Comment: When I the object in my main for the UserSelectLogin function and use the pass by reference method would I write it like this. userName = LoginUser.UserSelectLogin();